# Mongoose remove redundant indexes

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Mongoose provides a way to add new indexes automatically on app start using `autoIndex` option.

But is there some option that allows to drop redundant indexes that weren't defined?

For instance I created index manually that I don't define with Mongoose, can it drop it automatically during the launch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a script that

For each model:

1. Compares
   new model schema indexes `model.schema.indexes()`
   with currently existing in db `model.collection.indexes()`
   to find redundant indexes
   (the comparison is done by index `keys`, `names` and `options` (including `weights` comparison for text indexes))
2. Drops these redundant indexes
   `model.collection.dropIndex(indexName)`
3. Creates new indexes
   `model.ensureIndexes()`
   Schema should have `{ autoIndex: false }` options for this to work

Also as we run in cluster environment we need to have locking mechanism.
Acquiring the lock:

```
db.collection('dbchangeloglock').findOneAndUpdate(
  { locked: false }, { locked: true }
);
```

---

Please mind that its not recommended to use this automatic index updates in production because:

- indexes build in series can take a lot of time and meanwhile your app will be paralyzed;
- it's easy to drop important indexes/create redundant due to developers mistake in the code. Creating indexes in the shell seems more reliable.